# Cannot fopen network file (via UNC path) when running PHP in IIS

Tags: php, iis

I can't access/read a file located on a network shared folder when running this code in IIS. The folder in question is set up to allow all users. *If however, I run the php script through the command prompt it works fine.* Doing a shell_exec('whoami') through the command prompt yields the correct user but, through the browser it comes back empty.

This is definitely something to do with setting up the proper permission or setting up the server with the right user or something along those line. I do not know much about servers so, any help on how to solve this problem or any experiment that would yield any clue is greatly appreciated.

Below is the code which is very simple and strait forward (again is IIS 2003 server PHP 5.2)

```
<?php 
$theFile="\\\\192.168.0.16\\geo\\junk.txt"; #network file does not works
#$theFile="junk.txt"; #local file works fine
$handle = fopen($theFile, "r");
if($handle){
    while (!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        echo $buffer."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: are you sure it's "empty"? shell_exec returns a PHP `null` on error or not output from the exec'd program.

Comment: Well, it simply doesn't return anything visible. So, if I do echo "-->".shell_exec('whoami')."<--"; then all I see is --><-- where as if I ran it through the command prompt I get the user which in this case was -->tzhan_admin<-- which was the previous tech.

Comment: Have you tried exec instead of shell_exec

Comment: `var_dump(shell_exec(...))` is better. it'll give you type/size info as well.

Comment: I'll have t try it tomorrow. Anything else that could help me debug this problem?

Comment: 1) shell_exec('whoami') in command prompt --> usa90prod-db01\tzhang_admin   
2) exec('whoami') in command prompt --> usa90prod-db01\tzhang_admin  
3) var_dump(shell_exec('whoami')) in command prompt --> string(28) "usa90prod-db01\tzhang_admin"  
4) var_dump(exec('whoami')) in command prompt --> string(27) "usa90prod-db01\tzhang_admin"  


5) shell_exec('whoami') in browser --> nothing was displayed  
6) exec('whoami') in browser --> nothing was displayed  
7) var_dump(shell_exec('whoami')) in browser --> NULL
8) var_dump(exec('whoami')) in browser --> string(0) ""

Answer (score 0):

Well, we couldn't exactly figure out what the cause of the problem was except that it was some sort of permission issue on the server where my script lives. The workaround was to create another website on the server and copy the files there. We went through every setup we could think of but, we didn't find anything different but, hey it is working now. I mean, there was a bit more to it than just doing that like creating a virtual folder of the share network address and setting the correct password but, the main fix was just create a new website on the server and forget about the headaches of the old one. Hopefully we didn't break anything while doing all the debugging